# searching a query with fields that need putting into array

Tags: php, mysql

not sure if I am attempting this correct but I have a MySQL database that stores Latitude, Longitude and vehicles along with other fields. The issue I am having is that I am storing the vehicles in the database like  '1:4:7:8:9' etc. 1 being Car but that's not important. The code I have works getting the result based on the long,lat but I need it to get results if the vehicles type is also a match, so I need to add something to the query to see if either 1 or whatever is in that field that contacts '1:4:7:8:9'

The code is

```
    include 'db.php';

$origlat = "53.83428999999999";
$origlon = "-3.0399797000000035";
$vehicle_req = "1";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(53.83428999999999) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-3.0399797000000035) ) + sin( radians(53.83428999999999) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM clients HAVING distance < 30 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$id = $row['id'];

echo "found";
echo $id;
```

Thankyou and I hope this is clear? Thanks, Zak

Comment: 1) '1:4:7:8:9' is combination of `id` and long,lat and ... ? 2) You want search this string and if there where '1:' then return it's row? @zak

Comment: No, its the vehicle id`s, the longitude and latitude is in their own fields. Because they may have several vehicles, ie 1:BMW, 2:Coach, etc. So if the search is for 2, 1 would and should not even show up, thanks

Comment: so your vehicle `id` starts with your searching number and `:` . use `like` to match rows with "2" or other numbers... find in my answer @zak

Answer (score 0):

If you want search 1 and 4 in `id` column:

```
/* MySQL Query Should be:
SELECT *, (...) AS distance FROM clients
HAVING distance < 30 
  AND INSTR( concat('-:',id,':') , ':1:') > 0
  AND INSTR( concat('-:',id,':') , ':4:') > 0
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
*/
```

to create this MySQL Query we need `for` loop for each number in `$vehicle_reqs`

```
$vehicle_reqs= array(1,4);
// fix part of MySQL Query
$sqlQuery = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(53.83428999999999) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-3.0399797000000035) ) + sin( radians(53.83428999999999) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM clients HAVING distance < 30 "

// conditions for all items in $vehicle_reqs array:
for( $i=0; $i<sizeof($vehicle_reqs); $i++){
    $sqlQuery = $sqlQuery . " AND INSTR( concat('-:',id,':') , ':".$vehicle_reqs[i].":') > 0 " ;
}

// another fix part of MySQL Query
$sqlQuery = $sqlQuery ." ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;" ;
echo $sqlQuery ;
```

How `INSTR( concat('-:',id,':') , ':4:') > 0` works ?

1- adding `:` to start and end of `id` column in memory.

2- finding first substring that is equal to ':4:'

3- if `INSTR()` not find any thing, retuns 0

Comment: That doesn't display any results??

Comment: Sorry, no I want to see if 1 or 4 is in the field containing 1:4:6:8:14:19, etc It doesn't have to start with anything. The field contains data like 1:2:6:7, These correspond to 1=car, 2=bike, etc. But When it is searched I want to see if that particular id(number) is there?

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste some rows of your table? how many items want to be search, 2 items (1,4) in 1:4:6:8:14:19

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I didn't really know to phrase it. I will try again. Forget the search query for the lont+lat. I have a field called 'vehicles' that contains data like '3:6:8:9:12' Each one of these represents a vehicle. The reason they are stored like that is because people may have more than one. So the search has to look to see if the selected '3' if there within the '3:6:8:9:12' field?

Comment: `INSTR( concat('-:',id,':') , ':3:') > 0` is true for '3:6:8:9:12' , I've edit my answer, take a look @zak

Comment: Ok thanks but how do I put that into the MySQL query?

Comment: Do you always have many items to search? always looking for `i` and `j` and may be `k` in ID column? if yes, it was answered in my Answer by using for loop to edit `$sqlQuery` , finally execute sqlQuery whith mysqli

Comment: just gives me error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR) in /homepages/34/d663395916/htdocs/g5.php on line 14

Comment: Your INSTR() code works but only gets one field from database when added with the $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(53.83428999999999) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-3.0399797000000035) ) + sin( radians(53.83428999999999) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM clients HAVING distance < 20 AND INSTR( concat(':',vehicles,':') , ':1:') > 0 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 40;");

Comment: And ive set 3 identical fields apart from their ID

Comment: My `for` syntax was wrong! because of `i` variable name :| change them to `$i` as I changed my code @ zak

Comment: change `concat(':',vechiles,':')` to `concat('---:',vechiles,':')` that `---` must be before `:` @zak

Comment: Can you comment vehicle column value for those unmatched rows and your last parts of query (no formulation of distance needed) @zak

Comment: Did you missed some thing in your `while` loop ? I thing you're assigning `$id = $row['id'];` and out of the loop using `$id`. This way returns last `$row['id']` @zak

Comment: @zak , Solved your problem? May be you need `1 or 4` while this query is `1 and 4`?